# Download excel file returned in response to $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, excel

$.ajax returns the entire excel file in response. I tried all possible ways to download but unable to get the excel properly. Below is my code snippet.

```
             df$.ajax({
                        url : "myUrl",
                        type: "POST",
                        data : {
                            method : 'exportLanguageTranslationFile',
                            requestJSON: requestJSON,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            responseType: 'file'
                        },
                        dataType: 'text',
                        async : false,
                        success:function(response){
                          var a  = df$('<a class="downloadFile"></a>')
                            .hide()
                            .attr({ download : "test-file.xlsx" , href : window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/octet-stream"}))});
                            df$('#fieldDialogData').append(a);
                            df$('.downloadFile').click();

                       }
                  });
```

I'm able to download the excel file also but it says the file format is wrong or it is corrupted. In response the "content-type" of file is "application/octet-stream" and file is of .xlsx format.

Comment: Please try to write content type as "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Comment: @SudhirOjha Thanks for the comment. Initially i tried "application/vnd.ms-excel" but it was working with .xls file and not with .xlsx. 

I tried following content-type 

1. application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
2. application/vnd.ms-excel
3. application/octet-stream

But none of them seems to be working.

Comment: Were you able to get this one resolved @ShaliniSingh?